# Retrofit REST request with '=' in body

Tags: android, rest, post, http-post, retrofit

I have a string like "key=value" which I want to provide in my REST POST requests body. e.g.:

`String content = "key=value";`

Once set and trasmitted my logout output tells me, that my '=' sign content was converted to a '\u003d' wihch results in "key\u003dvalue" in my REST POST request content. Then the server responds a 400 Bad Request..

**How can I prevent the '=' being converted to that unicode ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String content = "key\=value";
```